# Whirlpool refrigerator (6 year old) stops cooling

Tags: cooling, compressor

My refrigerator stops cooling and I heard clicking and buzzing from the back of it. I then bought new start relay and capacitor and replaced the old ones. But the problem remains (clicking, buzzing, no cooling). I checked other parts like condenser and evaporator fans. All of them are good and running well. Does it mean my compressor dead? But I checked the resistance of the compressor, the values look normal. What should I do? Any hints an helps are greatly appreciated!

Doug

Comment: How did you indicate the compressor was good? Resistance check only? You've seen all the fans working and there is no debris or ice? Is it defrosted fully (it could need it)? Why change parts if they aren't bad? An honest suggestion for anyone on the site is to NEVER shotgun parts on a prayer unless they don't care to throw the money and time away (in spades). Parts bought can be bad too, or mistakes or other damage is inroduced on installation, then you are chasing your tail 2x over or more. Yes the compressor could be bad. 5 years is an average sealed component warranty period.